# JS file in chrome is never cached

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, http, google-chrome, caching

I dynamically create javascript files on the server that contain translated strings.
**When I look at chrome inspector this file never gets cached, (other actual JS files that are in the Scripts folder do get cached)**
**Why isn't it?**

```
<script src="somepath/Scripts/translate-nl-BE.js"></script>
or
<script src="somepath/Scripts/translate-en-GB.js"></script>
```

this is mapped to the following MVC action:

```
[HttpGet]        
public ActionResult TranslateJS(string culturecode) {
     ViewBag.JSCulture = culturecode;
     Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
     return PartialView("TranslateJS");
}
```

here's the view:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>
<%
    string culturecode = ViewBag.JSCulture;
%>
var translations = <%=new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize((ViewBag.Translate as List<ERPManager.TranslationService.FlatTranslation>).Where(x=>x.CultureCode==culturecode).ToDictionary(t=>t.Key,f=>f.Value)) %>;
```

this basically just serializes a json array (I know this looks dirtyer than just returning a jsonresult but i can't ajax call this file, it need sto be linked into a script tag

This is the response I get from the server:

```
Cache-Control:private
Content-Length:10987
Content-Type:text/javascript; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 04 Apr 2013 10:15:11 GMT
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version:3.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

here's a preview of the file that get's returned: it's basically just a key value dictionary of translations.

```
var translations = {"vertaald":"Vertaald","gerelateerd":"Gerelateerd","details":"Details"};
```

Comment: how long do you want it to cache for? Will this change often?

Comment: As far as the browser is concerned, this file will never change so should be cached forever, but I could settle for a daily/weekly exipration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is an `expires` [HTTP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields)

You can set this in your MVC code:

```
[HttpGet]        
public ActionResult TranslateJS(string culturecode) {
   ViewBag.JSCulture = culturecode;
   Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";
   Response.Expires = (60*24);//24 hours
   return PartialView("TranslateJS");
}
```

Bear in mind if you set an expires header the ***browser* will not request the file again** until after the cached content has *"expired"*. Use with caution!